# How do I add a new file to a Clojure project with Leinigen or Calva?

Tags: visual-studio-code, clojure, leiningen, vscode-calva

So I create a project with Lein: `lein new app test`

I open it in VSCode `code test`

I run Calva. I then test some simple functions in test.core. Works fine. Now I wanna have a new file with it's own namespace.

I create the file `meat.clj` inside: `(ns test.meat)` and try a simple function: `(defn inc [a] (+ a 1))`

I now run lein repl: `lein repl` then I navigate to the namespace `(ns test.meat) => nil`

Then try the function `(inc 1) => Syntax error compiling at (C:\Users\felix\AppData\Local\Temp\form-init5552733050921187898.clj:1:1). Unable to resolve symbol: add in this context`

Restarting the Calva server does not help, it can't find this new file.

I guess there maybe be some way to add a new file to Calvas build so it knows where to look? But I have no idea where to do this. Any ideas? The add function works in core but not in my custom namespace.

Comment: Where exactly did you create `meat.clj`? How and where exactly do you require that file?

Answer (score 0):

Couple possibilities:

If the namespace is `test.meat`, `meat.clj` needs to be in a directory named `test`.

Also you `def`'d a function called `inc` then you referred to it as add.

Comment: Yeah sorry fixed typo, thanks! Yeah, the meat.clj is in the same dir as core.clj and once again. The core.clj works fine.

Comment: Check out this repl. I think this is what you're asking. https://replit.com/@gtoast/OptimalWelltodoCircles#main.clj

One thing I did that you didn't mention was add a deps.edn to set up the current dir as a source path.